# JSON data not inserted in a MongoDB with python / pymongo when it was good until yesterday

Tags: mongodb, insertion

I have a new problem since yesterday.
With pymongo library, i insert json data in a MongoDB with Python insert_one instruction:
And finally i append inserted_id in a log file:

```
res = [collection].insert_one(data)
msg = 'Insert of: {0}'.format(res.inserted_id)
# Write in a log file:
with open('insert.log', 'at') as f:
f.write(f'{datetime.now():%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S}'+" "+msg+"\n")
```

in insert.log: 
2020-01-14T17:00:07 Insert of: 5e1de587e26921a0ee78fa1c
2020-01-14T17:00:32 Insert of: 5e1de59fe26921a0ee78fa1e

But in MongoDB collection, total record count don't increase and i don't find theses records:

> `db.[collection_name].find().count()`
>   18748
>
> `db.Prize.find({_id : "5e1de587e26921a0ee78fa1c"})`
>
> => not found

It was good yesterday. Can you help me to understand why it does not work now?
Thanks you a lot.
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

Your code could add the data to any collection and any database for that matter. Consider adding the `collection` variable to your logging.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.